# How to convert more than one base64 format to pictures from CSV file with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to convert a list with base64 format from csv and call it as the first column. Could you please help me. With one row everything goes perfect, but if I put more than one row, it starts to giving me different error messages or create one picture with all the names in the table. Here is my code:

```
   $csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\Desktop\Pictures.csv -Delimiter "~" | Select

    $csv.documentbody, $csv.filename | ForEach-Object {
  
    $picname = $csv.filename
    $b64 = $csv.documentbody
    $filename = "C:\Users\Desktop\$picname"

    $bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($b64)
    [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filename, $bytes)
   
    }
```

Here is the sample of my data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRGV3.png)

I am pretty new with PowerShell and cannot understand why it is not possible to go row over row to read the data.

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hello! Would you mind highlighting your code and clicking the curly braces `{}` at the top of the editor to properly format your code, please? It makes it easier to read the question and have people answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the csv, don't try to iterate over the fields.

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\Desktop\Pictures.csv -Delimiter "~" | Select

$csv | ForEach-Object {

$picname = $_.filename
$b64 = $_.documentbody
$filename = "C:\Users\Desktop\$picname"

$bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($b64)
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filename, $bytes)

}
```